# How to save POST variables securely using entity api

Tags: 7, commerce, entities, security

I am creating a module that connects Drupal Commerce to Shipworks (a shipping management system). They communicate with each other using HTTP POSTs via a single endpoint URL on Drupal. One aspect I am trying to understand is how to handle the POST variables returned from Shipworks in a secure manner.

For example, when a shipment is created in Shipworks the corresponding order id ($_REQUEST['order']) and tracking number ($_REQUEST['tracking']) are posted to Drupal at the endpoint. How do I save the tracking number in a secure manner using the entity api? Can I use the following code?

```
if (is_int($_REQUEST['order'])) {
  $order_id = $_REQUEST['order'];
}
else {
  _outputError(40, "Not a valid order id.");
}

$order = commerce_order_load($order_id);

$order_wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper('commerce_order', $order);

$tracking = $_REQUEST['tracking'];

$tracking_number = str_replace(' ', '', strtoupper($tracking));

$order_wrapper->field_tracking_numbers->set($tracking_number);
$order_wrapper->save();
```

Comment: I am using hook_menu and an access callback to protect the endpoint. I added a new user role and a Shipworks user in Drupal. The Shipworks user has the permission to access to the endpoint. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on how ShipWorks works. If it lets you specify a URL when it downloads the order data, you could use a secret key appended to the URL that you can use to authenticate a request as Ayeshk mentions. If it allows the merchant to specify a URL in a configuration form, at least you can set the secret key once and have the merchant copy it, kind of like how Drupal appends a secret key to the cron URL.

I also have a project upcoming that requires ShipWorks. Are you sharing the code publicly anywhere?

Comment: In Shipworks, you specify an endpoint, username and password. I created a user in Drupal with the same username and password and gave it permission to access the endpoint via a hook_menu access callback. My main concern is if somehow the endpoint, username and password were compromised I could be susceptible to an sql injection. Yes, I can share what I have so far. I will post it to Github and then post the url here. Thank you for your help.

Comment: The code is available on Github at https://github.com/pnigro/commerce_shipworks. It does require some custom fields attached to the order entity including field_payment_status, field_order_admin_notes, field_tracking_numbers and field_order_phone_number. The module does work. It just needs a little love. Any comments or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.